# What is the logic behind seperating Shift moves/reduce moves and Goto moves in parsing table?

Tags: compilers

In the parsing tables of SLR(0), LALR(1) and LR(1) I have seen that shift moves and reduce moves have separate columns from Go-to Moves. What is the logic behind this?